# Is it possible to open a blob without saving it to file

Tags: delphi, blob, firebird

My IDE is Delphi 10.3.

I have a Firebird 2.5 table, and the attachment field type is Binary Blob. Can I open this stored file (image, word, excel, pdf, txt, ...) without save to disk?

If this is not possible, I save the file, and after open or modified, how can I delete this file?

Comment: How do you want to open the file? With their standard software like e.g. MS Office or Adobe Reader? Then you need to save it to disk. You can save it as a temporary file using ``TPath.GetTempFileName`` from unit ``System.IOUtils``.

Comment: If whatever you want to use can ingest a stream or similar then it should be possible, if the library or application requires a file, then you obviously have to use a file. In other words, be specific, and pick one and only one thing you want to solve with this question, don't ask about multiple things (especially not without specifying with what application or library you want to open them).

Comment: This question is not related to Firebeird in any way, I would suggest to remove the tag.

Answer (score 3):

If the software that you use to open the content allows opening anything other than file then yes. It may be a named or unnamed pipe, shared memory, OLE IStream interface, etc.

Otherwise it may be complicated but [still possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system).

In the worst case you can use ordinary temporary files, but do not forget to use the flags `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` to avoid polluting file system.

Comment: Projected filesystems looked interesting. But as a general solution for user's machines it doesn't really work as [the feature isn't enabled by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/enabling-windows-projected-file-system)

Comment: @IanBoyd That's a task for installer or an item in System Requirement section of documentation, nothing more. In any case if the call failed or OS is too old code can fall back to usage of temporary files. It could be less effective but more portable.

Comment: Oh i know. But we prefer Delphi, and it's single-executable, xcopy deploy/portable installation abilities. And while we could spend months trying to creata a custom filesystem, and get WiX up and running. And there's no API, you have to powershell it; and probably enable powershell, and turn on flag to let powershell work. It's much easier to just write it to the hard drive and clean it up later. "Why does the software now require an installer and an administrator?" "Well, i didn't want to have to delete a temporary file." Software development is the art of adding value faster than cost.

Comment: @IanBoyd Looks like PS isn't powered by magic and there is API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/ Porting it into Delphi may be a challenge though.

Comment: As long as the engineering and technical nightmare that is suddenly required, not to mention it's an entirely different deployment system, and now requires administrator privileges, changing global settings on the user's PC, all because....we didn't want to delete a temporary file. It would be better to use `http.sys` to just serve it. Yes, it will trigger a UAC prompt, and firewall, and anti-virus, and the IT departments will be livid; but it's better than the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Use your DataSet's [`CreateBlobStream()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream) method to get a `TStream` to the blob data of an active record. You can the read the data from this stream and use it however you want.